# workflow toolbox not updated with new activity

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, toolbox

I've added to the activity pack the following activity:

```
namespace TeamFoundation.Build.ActivityPack
{
    using System;
    using System.Activities;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client;

    [BuildActivity(HostEnvironmentOption.Agent)]
    public sealed class CheckSlothInitialized : CodeActivity
    {
        [RequiredArgument]
        public InArgument<string> DbUser { get; set; }

        [RequiredArgument]
        public InArgument<string> DbPassword { get; set; }

        [RequiredArgument]
        public InArgument<string> DbServer { get; set; }

        [RequiredArgument]
        public InArgument<string> DbName { get; set; }

        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
        {
            string connString =  String.Format(
                            "data source={0};Integrated Security=false;Initial Catalog={1};User ID={2};Password={3}",
                            DbServer, DbName, DbUser, DbPassword);


        }
    }
}
```

After that I compile it I can't find it in the toolbox. I'm going to choose items in the toolbox and choosing the dll of my activity, but even then I can't find it in the list of System.Activities Components.

Comment: Is this a referenced assembly or are you attempting to create an assembly that can be in the toolbox without referencing it?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow these check points.

1. Clean and rebuild your solution.
2. If your activity is in independent project (activity library) and you are referring this activity in a project containg xaml or xamlx file make sure all referenced dll should be added in reference.
3. Try to add this activity as code behind in a workflow and execute it, is there any exception thrown?

Comment: #1 worked for me in my situation, where I created the custom activity, XAML, and libraries in a test server, then moved them to Production where the custom activity didn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

Just review in an exhaustive way if each opened are closed ({) are in the right position